# return token from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults

Here is my code in a swift file to keep token in user device:

```
struct DefaultsKeys
{
static let token  = ""
}

class DataContainerSingleton
    {
 static let sharedDataContainer = DataContainerSingleton()

var token: String?


var goToBackgroundObserver: AnyObject?

init()
   {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        token = defaults.object(forKey: DefaultsKeys.token) as! String?


       goToBackgroundObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground,
        object: nil,
        queue: nil)
      {
        (note: Notification!) -> Void in
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        defaults.set( self.token, forKey: DefaultsKeys.token)

        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
}
```

Then when I get the token from Alamofire request I save it as :
`DataContainerSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token = usertoken`

but when I go to viewdidload and check if `DataContainerSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token != nil` it return nil after I re-run the project! even when I print DataContainerSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token it prints nil!

Where is my mistake pleas

Edit: 
here is what I've tried but it returns nil @Paulw11

```
`struct DefaultsKeys
 {
    static let token  = "token"
 }


 class DataContainerSingleton
 {
     static let sharedDataContainer = DataContainerSingleton()



 var token: String? {
didSet {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(token, forKey:DefaultsKeys.token)
    defaults.synchronize()

 }

 }


 }`
```

Comment: Add a print statement in your goToBackgroundObserver, or set a breakpoint, and make sure that code is being run when your app goes into the background.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using all of this complicated logic? Saving to NSUserDefaults is low impact; you should simply save it in a `didSet` for the token property.  Also, make sure you load the value back when you initialise your class.

```
class DataContainerSingleton
{
    static let sharedDataContainer = DataContainerSingleton()

    var token: String? {
        didSet {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(token, forKey:DefaultsKeys.token)
        }
    }

    init() { 
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard 
        self.token = defaults.object(forKey:DefaultsKeys.token) as? String 
    }
}
```

Also, you need to provide a key name for your default:

```
struct DefaultsKeys
{
    static let token  = "token"
}
```

Comment: here is what I've tried but it returns nil @Paulw11  `struct DefaultsKeys
{
    static let token  = "token"
}


class DataContainerSingleton
{
    static let sharedDataContainer = DataContainerSingleton()
    
  

var token: String? {
didSet {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(token, forKey:DefaultsKeys.token)
    defaults.synchronize()

}
    
}


}`

Comment: Aside from the unnecessary synchronise that looks ok. How are you setting the token?

Comment: after request call I did this 

`let usertoken = JSON(value)
                    
                    if let id = usertoken["token"].string {
                       DataContainerSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token = id`

Comment: Chances are your `if let...` isn't matching then

Comment: I get the token like this Optional("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY...") then `DataContainerSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token = id` works just fine because when I print it right after saving it prints the token. The issue is it does not print after running the app again @Paulw11

Comment: Please show how you load the token back from defaults

Comment: **override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let check = DataContainerSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token
        if check != nil {
            print("hasToken")
        } else {
            print("needs to login ")
        }** @Paulw11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128674/discussion-between-paulw11-and-leo0019).